# Hibernate Search with Lucene on Spring Web

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I am development one Spring 3.2 webapp. I am hoping to somebody cant help me with this.

I try get all Sites with "test" word in "name" field in "Site" db table.

Site Table row:

id: 1
name: "test"
...

Site.class

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Spatial
@Table(name = "site")
public class Site implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    private String name;

...
}
```

DAO class

```
@Override
public List<Site> getSite(String word) {

    //word = "test" at this point on debug.

    QueryBuilder builder = Search.getFullTextSession(this.getCurrentSession()).getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Site.class).get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = builder.keyword().onField("name").matching(word).createQuery();

    org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = Search.getFullTextSession(this.getCurrentSession()).createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Site.class);

    return hibQuery.list();
}
```

getCurrentSession() is the Session returned by SessionFactory Spring bean.

**Question is this method allways return null List.**

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I had to call createIndexer().startAndWait() before lucene query.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e396